# Unboxing needed for tuples but not for types

Tags: f#, boxing, unboxing

Can someone explain the following, it seems a little inconsistent.

This line of code is invalid:

```
let l = [("Hi", 1); ("Ho", "One")]
```

Because the tuples are different string*int vs string*string    OK.

This line of code is also invalid:

```
let (m: (string*obj) list) = [("Hi", 1); ("Ho", "One")]
```

I explicitly tell it it's a list of string*obj tuples, but it doesn't automatically
cast the 1 and "One" to obj.    OK with that too.

This line of code IS valid:

```
let (n: (string*obj) list) = [("Hi", unbox(1)); ("Ho", unbox("One"))]
```

In this case I explicitly unbox 1 and "One" and it works.

Here's where I think things get a little inconsistent.
Take the following:

```
type thing =
    {
        name: string
        value: obj
    }

let (p: thing list) = [{name="Hi"; value=1}; {name="Ho"; value="One"}]
```

That code is valid. The values 1 and "One" are both assigned to the 'value' which is an obj.

Why do I not need to unbox for a member of a type, but I for an item in a tuple?

Comment: Yes, inconsistent. F# injects `box`, sometimes. Never injects `unbox/:?>` - that's unsafe. Note your example really reads `("Hi", unbox (box 1))` same as `("Hi", box 1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is somewhat inconsistent, but it actually makes some sense in this case.

The main point is that the compiler never inserts boxing anywhere inside a sub-expression of an expression. It only does this immediately - when calling a method or function (that takes `obj`) or when assigning values to record fields. However, it never <sup>(*)</sup> inserts boxing when this would be needed inside some larger expression.

So in your example, when the compiler sees `("Hi", 1)` and `("Ho", "One")`, it just creates two tuples with types `string * int` and `string * string` - and then it fails because these do not match.

When the compiler sees `{name="Hi"; value=1}`, it figures out that you are creating a `thing` and so it boxes the value argument to `obj` automatically (and then you end up with a valid list of things).

---

(*) The only exception is when you create an array or list of values, but this is an ad-hoc special case in the compiler (which happens to be quite useful, but does not really help you, because you'd need to add boxing not just inside a list, but inside a tuple inside a list). This is valid though:

```
let (arr:obj list) = [ 1; "hi" ]
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It makes sense, but caused me a bit of head scratching for a while. I get so used to F# seemingly being telepathic about what I'm doing with types that it's all the more confusing when I try something *clever* and it refuses to play along.